# Invalid Syntax while importing dataset

Tags: python

So I have a script that trains on video files, and so have a dataset.py file to work on it.
Whenever I am trying to run the script it throws an `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error even though I have
1) set the path correctly
2) gave the whole path

My folder structure is `/home/Videos/project_folder_name/data/train`
and my script is

```
class Dataset:
def __init__(self,  
             folder:/data/train,  
             resize:(int, int),  
             batch_size:int,  
             timesteps:int,  
             windowsteps:int,  
             shift:int,  
             train:bool):  
    self.folder  = folder  
    self.resize = resize  
    self.batch_size = batch_size  
    self.timesteps  = timesteps  
    self.train = train  
    self.images = sorted(os.listdir(folder + 'images/'))  
    self.labels = open(folder + 'labels.txt').readlines()  
    self.data = self._sliding_window(self.images, shift, windowsteps)
```

This error has been troubling a lot.

Comment: What's `folder:/data/train` supposed to do?

Comment: it is supposed to include the path so that I can refer it using ``` self.folder  = folder```

Comment: Basically you have written some code which is not Python.  Try a Python tutorial first.

Comment: Did you mix up type and parameter in a type annotation and additionally forgot to quote your string?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't tthink you understood the question very well

Comment: @KlausD. even I thought so too earlier but it did not happen. I have updated the question with entire definition, please look into it.

Comment: @AshwinPhadke have you opened it using something like IDLE or a text editor which will show you where the syntax error is occurring?

Comment: @BrodyUnderwood Yes, it is occuring at the same line of `  folder:/data/train ` , gave it as a string using ' ' and " " still did not solve also gave // for escape character issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting it into SublimeText3 (I highly recommend you use a text editor which will help you find syntax errors like this)

Most of your errors boil down to not properly indenting the lines.  I was able to complete my build once it was formatted like this

```
class Dataset:
    def __init__(self,  
         folder:data/train,  
         resize:(int, int),  
         batch_size:int,  
         timesteps:int,  
         windowsteps:int,  
         shift:int,  
         train:bool):  
        self.folder  = folder  
        self.resize = resize  
        self.batch_size = batch_size  
        self.timesteps  = timesteps  
        self.train = train  
        self.images = sorted(os.listdir(folder + 'images/'))  
        self.labels = open(folder + 'labels.txt').readlines()  
        self.data = self._sliding_window(self.images, shift, windowsteps)
```

**EDIT:**
I know formatting on the website can be odd so if this code didn't solve your problem let me know and I'll delete or edit.

Comment: Thank you so much that helped, I agree with you, I was editing the code using VS Code, changed to IDLE and the error was just as you pointed out. Text editors really are troublesome sometimes.